# Display custom field value as a hyperlink

Tags: custom-field

Using the following code in order to display custom field value, how can I automatically make it into a hyperlink?

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['website']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
  echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
?>
```

Presently if website value is set to http://www.abc.com then it would display http://www.abc.com instead i'd like for it to display as Click Here where it hyperlinks instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
  $custom_fields = get_post_custom($post_id); //Current post id
  $my_custom_field = $custom_fields['website']; //key name
  foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value )
  echo $key . " => <a href='" . $value . "'>Click Here</a><br />";
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Brady.. small question though.. how can i include an image in place of Click here. I tried putting in <img src="http://www.something.com"> but I get php error.

Comment: yes image can be used but use single quotes `'` around the `something.com` or escape your double quotes like so: `\"`